# Facebook Graph API Required Friend's Info

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios4, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve my Facebook user's friend info like *Email*, *Town*, *Interests*, *Like* etc in my iOS app.

I am using the following Facebook Graph API.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends.
```

but it just returns the friend name and id. Is their any way to retrieve other information about the friends?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

No, you can only access the names and id's. You can only access more information about the friends, if they've also authorized your application and you have a valid access token.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when your user adds the application you can ask them for extended permissions like "friends_about_me", then you  can read info for all your user's friends just with that users access token, but your user has to agree to that permission first

Comment: Thanks PaulPro.

Which Graph api i should call to retrieve,these info.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends.

the above link just give's me friend name and its id.


could you please help me via skype.

Thanks once again.

Comment: I'm not sure what your Skype name is, but you should continue requesting /me/friends and then you should loop through the results and for each friend you should request graph.facebook.com/(friend_id). For profile photos you don't need any special permissions either, just send a request to graph.facebook.com/(friend_id)/picture

Answer (score -1):

No you can not access information like email, Phone....
but you can access the Name, Id, location, link, birthday, profile photo..

Comment: How can i do that?could you please tell me in detail.

Thanks

Comment: first of all you have to get the friend ID Like this
`String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends";
     String response = Util.openUrl(url, "GET", params);
     
     JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
     JSONArray array = json.optJSONArray("data");`

then using after getting id put id as below and get the detail
`params.putString("format", "json");
    params.putString("access_token", accessToken);
    
    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+Id;
    String response = Util.openUrl(url, "GET", params)`

and extract the details from json into string